# There is already an open Data Reader associated with this Command which must be closed first Exception

Tags: c#, database, datareader

I am getting an exception called There is already an open Data Reader Associated with this command which must be closed first, I tried to look up solution on Google I tried using MARS=true in connection string and also kept everything inside USING but it didn't solved the problem.
i get an Exception in  line
 ***cm.ExecuteNonQuery();***

```
public void UpdateActionSchedule(string actionScheduleKey, string note, string PEOPLE_CODE_ID)
{

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=123; database=abc; user id=qwe; password=qwe;"))
    {
        con.Open();

        if (note == "" || note == null)
        {
            string UPDATE_COMPLETE = String.Format("UPDATE ACTIONSCHEDULE SET EXECUTION_DATE = '" + DateTime.Now + "', COMPLETED = 'Y', REVISION_OPID='WFLOW' where UNIQUE_KEY = '" + actionScheduleKey + "' and people_org_code_id='" + PEOPLE_CODE_ID + "'");
            SqlCommand cd = new SqlCommand(UPDATE_COMPLETE, con);
            cd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cd.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            string oriNote = "";
            string GET_NOTE = String.Format("SELECT NOTE FROM ACTIONSCHEDULE WHERE people_org_code_id='{0}' and UNIQUE_KEY='{1}'", PEOPLE_CODE_ID, actionScheduleKey);
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(GET_NOTE, con))
            {
                // SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (dr.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            oriNote = dr["NOTE"].ToString();
                        }

                        note = oriNote + " " + note;
                    } 

                    //string UPDATE = String.Format("UPDATE ACTIONSCHEDULE SET Note = '" + note + "' where UNIQUE_KEY = '" + actionScheduleKey + "' and people_org_code_id='" + PEOPLE_CODE_ID + "'");
                    //SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(UPDATE, con);
                    //cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    //cm.Dispose();

                    string UPDATE_COMPLETE = String.Format("UPDATE ACTIONSCHEDULE SET EXECUTION_DATE = '" + DateTime.Now + "',Note = '" + note + "', COMPLETED = 'Y', REVISION_OPID='WFLOW' where UNIQUE_KEY = '" + actionScheduleKey + "' and people_org_code_id='" + PEOPLE_CODE_ID + "'");
                    SqlCommand cmw = new SqlCommand(UPDATE_COMPLETE, con);

                    cmw.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    cmw.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated:  You _need_ to parameterize your queries instead of doing string concatenation. Here is a [relevant article as to why](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx)

Comment: Well. the error seems pretty clear to me. You need to call _dr.Close_ before issuing the last update command. But really your way to write sql commands is very dangerous. Fix it ASAP with parameters. Apart from SQL Injection, what do you think will happen if your field NOTE contains a single quote?

Comment: Also do not explicitly call Dispose - rather wrap your code inside using(var cmw = new SqlCommand(...)) .

Comment: @Steve dr.Close() sloved the problem , I will try to use parameters,I am new to coding and leaning by looking some video on youtube, thanxs for helping me, It gives exception Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''. And i don't know how to give +1 to comments, or I would give you. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second half of the code, you have a loop over `cmd` / `dr`, and **inside** that loop, you use `cmw` with `ExecuteNonQuery`. That means you're trying to execute two commands at once. Since you've already completed the loop: just move that code *outside* the `using` on the `dr`.

However, it *looks* like you could also do all of this in a single round trip with better SQL.